# Why while (std::cin >> foo) syntax does not work?

Tags: c++, cin

I was reading some C++ text at the address: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/new/istream-and-while.html.

According to the text, the I wrote this code:

```
int sum = 0, value;
while(cin >> value) 
{
    cout << "value: " << value << endl;
    sum += value;
}
cout << "sum: " << sum << endl;
```

If the input was: `1 2 3 4 5`

Then the while loop did not stop as I expected. Am I misunderstanding something? (I was using MS Visual C++ 2005)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your while loop will read input until the input stream is closed. In the Windows console that means until the user presses Ctrl+Z.

If you want to read input until the user presses enter, you need to do things differently. For example you could read the entire line using getline and then put that line into a stringstream and read from that in a while-loop - or you could use the `peek()` method of the `istream` class after reading each value, to check whether the next character in the stream is a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a special value for exiting the loop.

For example:

```
int sum = 0, value = 0;
while(value != -199) 
{
    cin >> value
    if(value != -199)   {
    cout << "value: " << value << endl;
    sum += value;
    }
}
cout << "sum: " << sum << endl;
```

This loop will only exit if you press -199(not necessarily -199, I've chosen it because it is trivial for most programs). It could be 0 or -1 if you won't use them as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

> In the Windows console that means until the user presses Ctrl+Z

I'll note that this isn't necessarily *true*, regarding the top answer.

The input operator will remain indefinitely active while in the loop until it becomes *untrue*, or *false*. By it's very nature, it's looking to take user input for an *integer*. Given your example, you must enter any non-integer to make it evaluate to false.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the while loop. `cin >> value` only once.

Comment: While that works, it changes the meaning of the program significantly (and renders other parts of the source code obsolete).